# JS Calendar two days short

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a calendar using Javascript (Vue JS). I have this little method to help get the days in the month:

```
daysInYearMonth(y,m){
  return new Date(y, m, 0).getDate()
}
```

If I console.log the above I get 31 as it's July. However, when it comes time to use this value:

```
this.days = [...Array(this.daysInYearMonth(this.year, 
  this.month)).keys()]
}
```

I console.log this.days and get 29 days, two short. If I simply try to add two then the other months are off. Here is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/eRrRvm?editors=0011).

NOTE: I am intentionally not using Moment.js and even though I agree it's better, the team decided to go with only Vue and vanilla JS.

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar I believe this is all the related code. But I do see the value in having the code executable in the question so that if the link ever goes bad it still has value. I will create a snippet, I was not aware of this feature, thank you!

Comment: `new Date().getMonth()` is, today, 6. And Array(x) will be zero based.

Comment: `daysInYearMonth()` returns the days in the *previous* month, day 0 of the current month is the last day of the previous month.

Comment: If you're looking for something more modular than moment you might have a look at [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`daysInYearMonth()` is returning the number of days in the month before the one you ask for. When you use day `0` in a date, it means the last day of the month before it. That's why you get `30` for July, not `31`. So to get the last day of the current month, you need to use the next month.

```
daysInYearMonth(y,m){
  return new Date(y, m+1, 0).getDate()
}
```

The next problem is that array keys start at `0`, but days in months start at `1`. So when you do `Array(this.daysInYearMonth(this.year, 
  this.month)).keys()` it returns an array from `0` to `30` rather than `1` to `31`. The simplest way to fix this is to write a loop that starts at `1`, rather than playing games with arrays.

```
let lastday = this.daysInYearMonth(this.year, this.month);
this.days = [];
for (let d = 1; d <= lastday; d++) {
    this.days.push(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- First of all:

In `return new Date(y, m, 0).getDate()`
you should use m + 1, as 0 takes the last day of the previous month (see http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-3.php)

- Secondly:

`this.days` is zero-based, but days in a month aren't. So, you count from 0-30 instead of 1-31.

I hope this helps you out. Greets